# Over which fields $x^{4} - 2x^{3} + 2x^{2} - 2x + 1$ can be factorized to linear factors

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Over which of the following fields $x^{4} - 2x^{3} + 2x^{2} - 2x + 1$ can be factorized
>   to linear factors?
>
> 1. $\mathbb{C}$ 2. $\mathbb{Q}$ 3. $\mathbb{Z_2}$ 4. $\mathbb{Z_3}$

There is no answer in the textbook, so I wanted to check if my solution is correct.

After linear factorization over reals I get the following factors:
$(x-1)(x^{2}+1)(x-1)$

1. Over $\mathbb{C}$, **Yes**, (x-1)(x-1)(x+i)(x-i)
2. Over $\mathbb{Q}$, **No**, because $(x^{2}+1)$ doesn't have roots over $\mathbb{Q}$
3. Over $\mathbb{Z_2}$, (I am not sure if that is a correct step) first, I convert $x^{4} - 2x^{3} + 2x^{2} - 2x + 1$ to $\mathbb{Z_2}$, so we get $x^{4}+1$, now there are factors $(x^{2}+1)(x^{2}-1)$, so the root is 1, as a check $1^{4}+1$ = 0, so **Yes**
4. Over $\mathbb{Z_3}$, First, convert $x^{4} - 2x^{3} + 2x^{2} - 2x + 1$ to $\mathbb{Z_3}$, so we get $x^{4} + x^{3} + 2x^{2} + x + 1$, now I couldn't find any linear factorization here and checks for 0,1,2 did not reveal any roots, so **No**

Questions:

a) Is the step with converting polynomial to $\mathbb{Z_2}$ and $\mathbb{Z_3}$ correct or I completely misunderstood that? If not, what would be the correct way?

b) Is there any useful trick to quickly determine if polynomial of degree n irreducible/not linearly reducible in $\mathbb{Z_k}$?

Comment: $x=1$ should be a root in every field...  Also, the polynomial is equivalent to $(x-1)^4+2(x-1)^2$, so that might help identify roots more easily.

Comment: Why convert when you have the factorization as $(x-1)^2(x^2+1)$. This means you need to only check if -1 is a square in the field. in $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ it is but in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$ it is not.

Comment: @Marco indeed...didn't think about it for some reason, thanks!

Comment: take a look at this one. For inspiration.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2887405/set-of-primes-p-which-x4-x3-2x2-2x-1-completely-factors-in-finite-field-o

Comment: Hmmm. That is actually a fair question for you to begin investigating, Jill. You have already considered primes $2$ and $3.$ Bigger question: for which primes $p$ does your polynomial factor completely in $\mathbb Z_p \; ?$

Comment: Note that @Marco has given a complete solution for *all* fields: Your polynomial factors into linear factors over a field if and only if that field contains a square root of $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

Note that you have $$ (x-1)^2(x^2+1)$$ so your only remaining concern about linear factorization is  $x^2+1$ which factors on $\mathbb {C}$ and $\mathbb {Z_2}$ and does not factor over $\mathbb {Q}$ and $\mathbb {Z_3}$ because in  $\mathbb {Z_2}$ we have $x^2+1=x^2-1$ which factors  and  in  $\mathbb {Z_3}$ we have $(x^2+1)=x^2-2$ which does not factor.